# Understanding the proof of $cl(cl(A))=cl(A)$

Tags: general-topology

I want to discuss a particular part of the proof of $cl(cl(A))=cl(A)$ in a topological space:

One way to proof this includes the following reasoning:

$x\in cl(cl(A)) \Rightarrow U_x\cap cl(A)\neq \emptyset\Rightarrow \exists y \in U_x \wedge y\in cl(A) \Rightarrow x\in  cl(A)$

where $U_x$ is a neibeorhood of $x$.

What I dont understand here is the last Implication. OK: I know that there is an $y$ in $cl(A)$ and this $y$ is aswell in $U_x$, but how can I know that my $x$ from the beginning is in $cl(A)$?

Comment: Unfortunately, in topology you will usually need to specify what definitions you are using (in this case, the definition of closure). As a sidenote, often it will be easier for people to read and understand your question if you replace all "math sentences" with plain English ones (as you did in your last sentence).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y\in cl(A)$ implies that the intersection of every neighborhood of $y$ with the set $A$ is nonempty. So here $U_x$ is a neighborhood of $y$, and hence $U_x\cap A\ne\emptyset$. Now, $U_x$ was just some random neighborhood of $x$. So we actually showed that if $U$ is any neighborhood of $x$ then $U\cap A\ne\emptyset$. Thus $x\in cl(A)$.

Comment: But why $U_x$ is a neighborhood of $y$? I think this is the point I don't get

Comment: @Averroes2 The most common definition of a neighborhood is an open set which contains the point. (unless you are using some other definition). Now, $U_x$ is an open set, because it is defined as a neighborhood of $x$. And it also contains $y$.